# Trying to use Vlookup or Index/Match

Tags: vlookup

2 columns are related (column A is customer ID, column B is customer name) In another column C, there are multiple instances of the customer id (column A) and I'd like to put a formula in column D that inputs the customer name from column B that corresponds to the customer ID in column C.

Answer (score 1):

try putting this in column D, change C1 to the correct row number

```
=VLOOKUP(C1,A:B,2,FALSE)
```